# How to use cron to delete files and folders using a text file?

Tags: cron

I am trying to remove some files every minute using cron job. So I created a text file for the that to remove. Below is the txt file that I have

remove.txt file

```
rm -vrf /desktop/files/*/out*
```

Here, Im trying to wander all the folders in files and remove files, folders that contains out.

in crontab I'm using

crontab -e

```
* * * * * /desktop/files/remove.txt
```

Here, I am getting permission denied. Please help me to figure out the reason. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
chmod +x /desktop/files/remove.txt
```

Usually, script files are named in such a way that humans know they are meant to be run as scripts. `remove.sh` could be a better name.